# Principal components regression vs other regression models following PCA

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, pca, dimensionality-reduction

My understanding of principal components regression (PCR) is that it is a linear regression performed on all or a subset of predictors obtained via PCA. All the resources I've read only apply linear regression following the PCA step, but I've found nothing that explicitly warns against using other regression models.

Does the regression model in PCR always have to be linear/OLS or can we use other GLM regression models (such as logistic, Poisson, or negative binomial regression)?

Comment: Sure, you can use the scores in any of the models you mention. The usual caveats apply regarding appropriateness of the chosen model and the appropriateness of using PC scores.